# SQL Server Version control using TFS 2010 which syncs directly with the Development Server

Tags: sql-server, version-control

We are planning to put out SQL Objects (Tables, StoredProcedures, UDF's and Views) under our existing TFS 2010 versio control. 
Is is possible that any check-in's made to the objects under TFS version control gets automatically sync'd to our Development server. The technical team here are not so interested in having to make changes at 2 different places (Development Server + Check-in at TFS server). Its an overhead process change for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my unique scenario. I used the Sql server management studio project by using the [TFS plugin](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=FAEB7636-644E-451A-90D4-7947217DA0E7&displaylang=en) for SSMS. Team can now easily make changes in the Development environment using SSMS and make check-ins at the same place. Nice and easy way to do things without additional overheads. However, this only solves the purpose of version control. I am still researching on how can we do schema compare and automated deployments using SSMS projects.

Comment: You seem to really want to go out of your way to do something that there are solutions too.  Be careful, there may be a reason that you have to hack a solution together.  Anyways, good luck!

Comment: Is there a version of this for TFS2010?

Answer (score 4):

Late answer, but I hope it can be useful:

Recently, I've tried to find the solution for a similar problem, and I've bumped into a sql source control add-in for SSMS that works with the TFS, and I found some answers by reading this article:

[SQL source control reduce database development time](http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/sql-source-control-reduce-database-development-time/)

I think it can be useful for you too (in case you couldn't solve your problem)

Hope I helped.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution by far to do this is to use [Red-Gate Source-Control](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/). You will not find a better and easier product to do this, and all the other benefits you get from using it is huge. For example, it integrates 100% into SQL Management Studio.

Comment: @Ryk: have you tried Visual Studio Database Projects? Also, does the Red-Gate product automatically deploy the database?

Comment: @John - Yes I have, and I find it primitive. In my opinion and DBA/Company that uses a tool like Visual Studio, (or any other tool that does everything automatically without control), to deploy databases to production servers is up for a big failure one day.

Comment: @Ryk: seriously? What if it does it automatically _and_ correctly? It's just doing a schema compare for you before the deployment. And you didn't answer my question about whether the Red-Gate product does automatic deployments, which is what the OP asked.

Comment: @John: Yes it does schema compare and give you a diff script. His question was not about automatic deployment, rather the ability to version control the database in some way, and then using it to update the Development server. @John - seriously give it a go, that RG software is fantastic.

Comment: @Ryk: He says, "Is is possible that any check-in's made to the objects under TFS version control gets automatically sync'd to our Development server." I think "sync'd" doesn't mean diff script. I've used the Red-Gate product, and liked it, and didn't think it could deploy.

Comment: @Ryk: it can deploy automatically, as part of a nightly build process? Can you provide a link to where it says that, because it didn't use to be able to do this.

Comment: @John: as with everything in TFS you have to do it manually. By default what you are proposing it does, does not work, you have to get a chainsaw out, cut it open and then butcher it, then it works, but that is the nice thing about VS & TFS, you can do it, IF you want to. In other words, pull some sleeves up, and you can do it, I am doing it in our environment right now. So I am not here to try an convince you, and reasoning with you seems pointless, so I would rather not waste any more time on this topic. OVER AND OUT....

Comment: @Ryk: I don't know what your problem is, but it certainly looks like [Visual Studio Database Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193294.aspx) can deploy automatically during a TFS automated build (see [An Overview of Database Build and Deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833165%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Red Gate's SQL Source Control can be used in conjunction with SQL Compare Pro's command line interface to automate the sync'ing of a schema to a target database. This is typically done as part of a build automation process but should also satisfy your requirement. A recent article by Troy Hunt describes this in detail (http://www.troyhunt.com/2011/02/automated-database-releases-with.html), or read Red Gate's technical paper (http://downloads.red-gate.com/HelpPDF/ContinuousIntegrationForDatabasesUsingRedGateSQLTools.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

You should use [Visual Studio Database Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193294.aspx).  You'll get the best of both worlds!  Source control and automated builds and deployment.

Comment: @Lwoody: can you post a link showing how one can deploy these during an automated build? Or else give an example of the settings for that?

Comment: Basically you'll use MSBuild with particular parameters for Visual Studio Database Projects.  Here's the link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833165(v=VS.100).aspx

Comment: @John, np.  How about a +1 for us heathens below 1K ;)

Comment: @LWoody: thanks for the reminder. I found the article very helpful.

Comment: I know about Visual Studio Database Projects. But the problem is the team here is so used to just making the changes in Development and simply moving it to Production using schema compare tool. They do not want any extra version control repository and the overheads associated with it in terms of extra check-ins, additional deployment cycle to Dev environment. So that was rejected

Comment: @PRABHATS: how does that differ from using SSMS projects? They still have to do schema compares manually. Using the Database Projects (the new ones, not the old kind), the compare is done automatically as part of the deploy. Careful: just because they contain scripts doesn't mean they're the same as the old database project type. They're not. They actually understand what the scripts mean.

Comment: Depending on the type of project but automated build is not always desirable in databases.